# How to make jQueryUI work in a ASP.NET Core web project

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I'm learning how to use [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) in an ASP.NET Core Web project. I've created a web project in VS2015 using `ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework)` template. I'm trying the following example of an [autocomplete widget](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/). Suppose I want to display this example page on views\Home\Index.cshtml view

**Question:**:

1. Where, in my project, should I place the `<script>....</script>` section of this example
2. Where, in my project, should I place the following files of the examples below: `jquery-ui.css`, `jquery-1.12.4.js`, `jquery-ui.js`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you are asking where to put the actual script files locally on your server. Since you are using remote links, you don't need to have local copies. If you want to store local copies and since you are using MVC, there are extension bundling options (see [HERE](https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier)) for better efficiency or you could just put your CSS files in YourAppName/Content and your script files in YourAppName/Scripts and reference them there.

As far as where to put your functions and JS/JQ scripts, my preference has always been to put them at the bottom of my code for better readability.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

(update to today's asp.net core version- 2.2)
if you are putting your scripts in `.cshtml` file you should place yours scripts in the middle ot these tags:

```
@section Scripts{
   your scripts...
   <script></script>
}
```